# ssrs subreport not showing when compiled via web app

Tags: service, reporting-services, reporting, subreport

I have this report which uses a tablix and on one of the rows I have a subreport.
Now in development preview everything works as expected. On the server instance online page it works flawlessly. 
When I get this report via my web application and send it (.pdf) to a user the subreport doesn't render. Any ideea why?

Exact error is: Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Subreport12', located at: ***. Please check the log files for more information.

there is nothing in the log files to help me.

Answer (score 0):

With the web-app it is not able to find the path of subreport. Instead of relative path give the absolute path in the report design.